# Enabling Overflow Indicators in Release Environment

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a semi no-code builder in Flutter Web similar to **FlutterFlow** and would like to implement a feature to show/hide overflow indicators (black/yellow strips) similar to what is available in debug mode.

[image: FlutterFlow demo]

The overflow indicators are painted using the `DebugOverflowIndicatorMixin` with the `paintOverflowIndicator` method, acting as a helper for rendering overflow strips. This mixin is used by `RenderFlex` and `RenderConstraintsTransformBox`.

The challenge I'm facing is that this feature only seems to work in debug mode. This is because the framework wraps the calls to `paintOverflowIndicator` with `assert`s, and `assert`s are removed in the released environment by Dart.

I'm looking for guidance on how to enable overflow indicators in a release web app. Are there alternative approaches or modifications that can be made to achieve this functionality in a production environment? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

To provide more context, I have explored the current implementation of `DebugOverflowIndicatorMixin` and the associated `paintOverflowIndicator` method. I have also reviewed the usage of asserts within the framework and how they impact the visibility of overflow indicators in debug versus release modes.

Comment: Here's the code for the DebugOverflowIndicatorMixin: https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/flutter/flutter@4cd32ffe784a59bc0563843b32f60a8a09528ec0/-/blob/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/debug_overflow_indicator.dart?L90